# Include header files from static library with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, include, static-libraries

I have a problem building a CMake project with a static library.
My project strucutre looks like that:

```
Foo/
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- lib/
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- libA/
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- libA.cpp
        |-- libA.h
        |-- libAB.h
|-- src/
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- main.cpp
    |-- srcDirA/
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- srcA.h
    |-- srcDirB/
        |-- CMakeLists.txt
        |-- srcB.cpp
        |-- srcB.h
```

And the */CMakeLists.txt look like that:

Foo/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(FOO)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

Foo/lib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(libA)
```

Foo/lib/libA/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library (staticLibA STATIC libA.cpp)
```

Foo/src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(srcDirA)
add_subdirectory(srcDirB)
include_directories(".")

add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo LINK_PUBLIC libA)
```

Foo/src/srcDirA/CMakeLists.txt is empty

Foo/src/srcDirB/CMakeLists.txt is empty

Now I am trying to include the header from my static library into my main project like this:

Foo/src/main.cpp:

```
#include "srcDirB/srcB.h"
#include "libA/libA.h"  

int main() {
   //...
   return 0;
}
```

If I try to build this with CMake, libA is generated but I am getting a fatal error:

> libA/libA.h: No such file or directory.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Do I have to [create a ProjectConfig.cmake file](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to create any Config files; these are for importing 3rd-party projects.

Since you're using CMake >= 3.5.1, you can esaily specify [usage requirements](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#build-specification-and-usage-requirements) for your libraries. Usage requirements are things like flags or **include directories** which clients need to build with the library.

So in Foo/lib/libA/CMakeLists.txt:, you'll do this:

```
add_library (staticLibA STATIC libA.cpp)
target_include_directories(staticLibA INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
```

Or, if you want the same include directory to apply to libA itself (which is likely), use `PUBLIC` instead of `INTERFACE`.

That's all you really need to do. However, given the modern CMake you're using, you should replace your use of the legacy keyword `LINK_PUBLIC` with its modern equivalent `PUBLIC`.

Also, since you mention both CMakeLists in `.../srcDir*` are empty, why have them there in the first place? You can easily get rid of both them and the related `add_subdirectory` calls.

Comment: Use still use `INTERFACE` but add `include_directories(.)`, what are the down-sides?